# Evaluating integral with inner derivative

Tags: integration

Hi I am failing to spot how to integrate this. By parts I'm guessing? Any hints into the right direction would be helpful...

> > $$ \int x\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(f\frac{df}{dx}\bigg) dx$$

where $f=f(x)$.

Would expanding the inner derivative operator work here?

Comment: Sorry,  I did not see any answers at all that time.  I will delete my comments. +5 from me

Comment: @Mark Viola,  another proof that servers are not fast enough :)

Comment: @dmtri That has happened to me too, so no worry.  Happy Holidays!  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac12 \frac{df^2(x)}{dx}$.  Then, integrating by parts reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int x\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)\,dx&=\frac12 x\frac{df^2(x)}{dx}-\frac12 \int \frac{df^2(x)}{dx}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12x\frac{df^2(x)}{dx}-\frac12 f^2(x)+C
\end{align}$$